# Compile Zlib Statically for PHP 5.6

Tags: php, docker, zlib

I am using the docker image `5.6.30-alpine` https://hub.docker.com/_/php/. I am getting the error

```
PHP Notice:  getimagesize(): The image is a compressed SWF file, but you do not have a static version of the zlib extension enabled in /var/www/builds/stage81/platform/class/Wm/View/FileInfo.php on line 55
```

I cannot find a way to make `zlib` to be compiled statically. I tried all possible options including

- Adding zlib-dev
- `./configure --with-zlib --with-zlib-dir=/usr`
- `./configure --with-zlib=/usr --with-zlib-dir=/usr`

None of them works and still getting the same message. Is there no way to make `zlib` to be compiled statically? Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. I am responding just in case somebody else comes across the same issue.

The root cause of the issue is my understanding on how Apache and PHP interacts. I was in the wrong assumption that Apache uses the installed PHP. It seems there are two different things. Installed PHP or PHP-cli never interacts with Apache. Apache uses `libphp5.so` for PHP integration. Since I was using `php5-apache2` it comes along its own `libphp5.so` where the configuration is `--with-zlib=shared`. So even if the installed PHP has zlib statically it has no impact for Apache. I have raised an issue with Alpine for this https://bugs.alpinelinux.org/issues/7284.